# Always add youtube clips to watch later list

Tags: youtube

I prefer to watch my youtube clips later on my computer rather then on my phone.
Currently if I encounter an interesting clip I want to add to my youtube 'watch later' list I have to:

```
* Open the link in youtube app
* Wait until youtube app has loaded
* Make sure the media volume is muted
* Wait until first buffering is done
* Stop playback
* Add the clip to 'Watch Later' list through the submenu
* Go back to the app I was using before I clicked the link
```

Is there a way to do this faster? Ideally all links normally opened in the youtube app should instead be added to the watch later list. Extra points if it doesn't disturb the flow in the original app so I continue reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is using an app like [Pocket](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pocket/com.ideashower.readitlater.pro) (formerly known as "Read it Later"). *Pocket* accepts input from all kind of apps via the "share" menu; I e.g. use it with my RSS reader, Twitter apps, Browser, and more. So far for the "Android end": Even before the buffer starts filling, press "Share", select "Pocket", done.

Now for your PC, *Pocket* offers addon for several browsers. For me, that's Firefox, and it's addon works like a charm: I've got a small icon next to my URL bar, which opens a (paged) list of saved entries which even offers a search/filter function – so it's easy to pick the wanted entry (here: Youtube URL) and watch the movie.

The "share process" on your Android device works in the background (gives you status information via "toast messages"), so it doesn't disturb you in whatever you're doing. As a side effect (you might already have taken that from my above description) you can do the same with a lot of other stuff you want to "consume later" – as long as it provides an URL: Tweets, web pages, RSS feeds, probably also Podcasts and more. And if you decide to check some of the stuff while on the road, *Pocket* offers a reader for that as well (included with the app).